# Cisco anyconnect 4.6 client disable some security feature

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, vpn, firewall, cisco-anyconnect

Last 3 year we are using cisco anyconnect with client version 4.5 and everything is good but recently i have install client 4.6 which has tons of additional feature which i am not interested and want to get rid on them because its misguiding folks.. this is what my client looks like when i start.

In short how do i disable all these unnecessary profile and keep it simple?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uninstall the AnyConnect packages and reinstall it, but uncheck the options for everything except Core in the setup wizard.

Comment: Holy smoke!!! you are amazing!!! i didn't realize when i installed client that you can skip that package.. default was select all... :)

Comment: @Satish Yep. All the rest are for when you're using the host scanning features to make sure the client is using proper antivirus and such before allowing the connections.

Comment: @Satish remember to accept the answer if it helped you. :-)

Comment: sorry stackexchange won't let you accept answer immediately :( you have to wait for few minute